# Flutter: How to prevent possible route change in go_router?

Tags: flutter, router

I want to listen to go_router before it makes changes in navigation stack.
For example to prevent deeplinks to stack on top of another:

```
GoRouter(
  routes: [],
  listener: (GoRouteState prevState, GoRouteState attemptedState) {
    if (attemptedState.location == 'home/details') {
      // prevent redirection
      return null;
    }
    // or allow redirection
    return attemptedState;
  }
)
```

Maybe there is something like this listener function?

Comment: I know with [`auto_route`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) you can use a route guard to modify navigation behavior. Not sure how one would achieve this with go_router. Maybe you could add a redirect method onto the `GoRoute` that does whatever check you need it to?